# How do i use fgets and strtok to get multiple inputs?

Tags: c, fgets, strtok

I am having trouble using `fgets()` and `strtok()` to receive an input and splitting them up accordingly.

Assuming I have a main menu that takes input 1-9, and every input leads to another function. I did that with just if statements and a break statement on every function. Now let say there is another command that takes a string, then a space, then 2 ints, how would I write it up in my menu?

That is any time in the menu, it can read just individual ints (1-9) and also read let say `"start 5,9,forward"` or `"start ,4,2,backwards"` in that menu. Do I write a logic that says if "start" is being input, go on go on, but I don't know how to make it so that it will then read for the space input after start and read the 2 ints and the last string.

Sorry if my question is a little confusing but I just want to know an example if receiving multiple inputs in a line and being able to manipulate those input variables.

Comment: Maybe you want `char buf[256], *p; fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin); p = strtok(buf, " ,"); while(p) { puts(p); p = strtok(NULL, " ,"); }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using `fgets` and `strtok`:**

It is pretty much what @Cool Guy said.

```
...
fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin);
char a[25], d[25];
int b, c;
char *p = strtok(buff, ", "); //this will cut the input at an occurrence of `,` or `' '`, whatever happens first. At this point you would have the string "start" pointed by `p`.
strcpy(a, p);
p = strtok(NULL, ", ");
if(p) {
    b = atoi(p);
    if(b < 0 || b > 9) {
        //input error
    }
}
p = ...
```

The rest is analogous.

**Using scanf solution:**

You can read the input using scanf (yes, it is a powerful function).

```
scanf(" %N[^,' '] ,%1d%*[^,' '] ,%1d , %N[^\n]", a, &b, &c, d);
```

`" %N[^,' ']"` will read the input until the first `,` or `' '` (blank space) is reached. Also, replace N with the size of `a` - 1;

`%1d%*[^,' ']` will read an integer with one digit and discard the rest of the input until a `,` is found and store it in `b`;

`%N[^\n]` will read the rest of the line and store it in `d`. Replace N with the size of `d` - 1.

There are tons of tricks that you can use with scanf.
Please note that all whitespaces are important inside scanf's format in this case. Also, **i am not treating the case where an user types a wrong input format**, but it is possible.

Comment: If you want to work specifically with `fgets` and `strtok`, let me know and i'll edit my answer.

Comment: yeah i would like it to be with fgets and strtok

Comment: @ProgrammingNoob Done.